# Win32 Dialog box: how to keep all objects in windows centered when resizing

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, winapi, dialog

I am building and maintaining a Win32 app using Visual Studio.

I have recently edited the `.rc` file adding `WS_THICKFRAME` to my dialog `STYLE` line for all dialog windows to allow them to be resizable.

My current problem is, when I resize a window, its content remains fixed to the left. How can I make the window's content remain centered when resizing using the border?

Pointing to any relevant documentation on this would also be helpful, as I have not had lucky finding that.

Comment: Handle the WM_SIZE message and resize/reposition your content.

Comment: You're looking for [dynamic layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dynamic-layout).

Comment: You could use [MoveWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) or [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) to adjust the position and size of the specified control in the [WM_SIZE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-size)

Comment: @IInspectable I notice the dialog that contains all the objects I want to move does not show Dynamic layout properties when i right click it in the Resource Viewer/Editor. So I one by one selected all the objects that are present on it, and made them all Moving Type BOTH and MovingX,MovingY both to 50. I also left Sizing Type as NONE. After doing this the resizing of the window no longer works (it allows me to drag, but no resizing occurs). I am not sure what the issue is here

Comment: Visual Studio's dialog editor is broken, and has been so for years. There's no hope that Microsoft would suddenly decide to put resources into fixing it. It's generally much less trouble editing the .rc file(s) manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reposition (rather than resize) the individual controls, an easy way would be to create a non-modal container dialog to hold the controls, make that dialog a child of the resizable dialog, and then when you handle `WM_SIZE` for the outer dialog, you only have to reposition that one non-modal dialog.

Your new position is `((newWidth- controlDlgWidth) / 2, (newHeight-controlDlgHeight)/2)`, where `controlDlgWidth`, `controlDlgHeight` are the width and height of the child dialog.

I say to use a non-modal dialog for this, so that you can continue using a resource script, rather than needing to add a whole bunch of explicit `CreateWindow()` calls.

Comment: Maybe I am too new and need a basic tutorial but could you explain how to create a modal dialog? I also dont understand how to make this modal dialog a child of my dialog. I also dont understand how to make all of the objects (that I want to move upon resize) children of this invisible modal dialog you recommend. I notice from resource view I can add a dialog, with several options like IDD_DIALOGBAR, IDD_FORMVIEW, etc.

Comment: A modal dialog is what you get from DialogBox*, it is the "regular" form of a dialog, and cannot be a child window. A non-modal dialog is created via The CreateDialog* functions, which returns an HWND, you can then use the SetParent API to make that HWND a child to another window (at least if it also has the WS_CHILD window style). If it doesn't have the WS_CHILD style it will merely change the owner.